# Spring injection of SessionFactory with inheritance giving NullPointers

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, dependency-injection, dao

In my design all of my daos inherit from a parent class, this parent class contains the hibernateTemplate field and a setSessionFactory which creates the hibernateTemplate upon the setting of the session using spring

The problem here is that even though it seems to get set but when I actually execute the code and the daos are called the hibernateTemplate object seems to be null. HOWEVER when I inject the Dao object instead of the parent generic class with the session factory it works like a charm

The part of the AbstractDaoSupport class

```
/** The hibernate template. */
private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

/**
 * Sets the session factory.
 *
 * @param sessionFactory the new session factory
 */
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.setHibernateTemplate(new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory));
}

/**
 * Sets the hibernate template.
 *
 * @param hibernateTemplate the hibernateTemplate to set
 */
public void setHibernateTemplate(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
    this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
}
```

This is the current problematic code where the hibernateTemplate is null when running

```
  <!-- the DataSource for application usage -->
    <bean id="applicationDataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/taxidb"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="abc"/>
   </bean>      

    <bean id="daoSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="applicationDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.iit.awt.application.domain.Driver</value>
                <value>com.iit.awt.application.domain.DriverRealTimeCurrentLocation</value>
                <value>com.iit.awt.application.domain.Journey</value>
                <value>com.iit.awt.application.domain.Customer</value>
                <value>com.iit.awt.application.domain.SystemConstants</value>
                <value>com.iit.awt.application.domain.DriverRequest</value>             
                <value>com.iit.awt.application.domain.Account</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager" 
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="daoSessionFactory"/>
    </bean> 

    <!-- JPA Daos -->
    <bean id="abstractDaoSupport" class="com.iit.awt.platform.support.AbstractDaoSupport">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="daoSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

And this is when the code works instead of the last pieced of code above under the "JPA Daos" comment the following is there

```
<bean id="driverLocationDao" class="com.iit.awt.application.dao.impl.DriverLocationDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="daoSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Another thing to note was that the class was previously abstract and I tried that with "abstract=true" as well as having it non-abstract the current way

Does anyone have an idea on why the hibernateTemplate object is null?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please post the class signature of your abstractdao

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your issue**

```
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.setHibernateTemplate(new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory));
}
```

you are ***not*** setting `sessionFactory` actually here, so it would stay `null`

---

**Better Way**

I'd done it following way, why to create template on our own..

**AbstractDAO**

```
public abstract class BaseAbstractGenericDao<EntityType, IDType extends Serializable> extends HibernateDaoSuppor  {

}
```

---

**HibernateTemplate Bean Defination**
<sub>with session factory injection</sub>

```
 <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

---

**HibernateTemplate Bean Defination**
<sub>with session datasource injection and other property setter injection</sub>

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>...</list>
</property>
<bean>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I used the HibernateDaoSupport and it worked

Comment: As of Spring 3.1 use of HibernateTempalate and HibernateDaoSupport is discouraged. Please check their docs for more information

Answer (score 1):

Who is injecting the hibernateTemplate in your code ? If you're extending HibernateDaoSupport , you only need to inject the sessionFactory . the getHibernateTemplate() method looks for the hibernate template in it's parent class. That is why the code below works

```
<bean id="driverLocationDao" class="com.iit.awt.application.dao.impl.DriverLocationDaoImpl">
   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="daoSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Here hibernate template initialization is not required . If you're not extending hibernateDaoSuppor, you will have to inject the template as @Jigar Joshi has mentioned .

Please note, Hibernate template use is not recommended as per Spring 3 recommendations [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html)

```
NOTE: As of Hibernate 3.0.1, transactional Hibernate access code can also be coded 
in plain Hibernate style. Hence, for newly started projects, consider adopting the
standard Hibernate3 style of coding data access objects instead, based on 
SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
```